# Can I allow a Bamboo build plan to fail, but still trigger deployment plans?

Tags: bamboo

We have a Bamboo "build plan" that is really just watching a git repository full of configuration files, with a deployment plan that pushes them to some servers (where they will be noticed by daemons that will do stuff outside the scope of this question). This is all nice and automated (the build plan automatically detects commits in the repository, a successful "build" automatically triggers multiple environments under the deployment plan).

We have some validation checks we can run in the build plan to detect some kinds of configuration errors - this provides a faster feedback cycle than waiting for the daemons to detect the bad input. However most of the configuration files are independent, so we don't want to turn an error that blocks a single file from being used into one that blocks any new files from being deployed at all.

Is there someway to have the build plan "fail" (in terms of flagging the build, and sending out alerts to the users whose commits were involved), but still have deployment go ahead? A suggestion I've had is to have two build plans, one that validates and one that doesn't - we key the deployment plan to the build plan that doesn't validate, and we get alerts from the plan that does validate. Is there anything nicer than this?

Comment: Do you want to deploy all the configs (including the "failed" ones) or just the ones that passed?

Comment: @AdamWestbrook We'd deploy them all. The kinds of error that can fail the early validation will fail "cleanly" in production. The validation is about getting feedback earlier, not about guarding production from the bad configs.

Answer (score 1):

Great question.
This is something that I could really do with as well.

However, after a lot of looking around, it does not seem possible. There is a feature request created over 3 years ago which might do what we need - https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BAM-1278 but somehow I can't see Atlassian working on that any time soon :(